# Hibernate Spring MVC Extremely Slow

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building manager web project with Spring MVC , Hibernate and MySQL. When i write the code to list all the regency i have in database. It run very fast in couple first times, but when i reload the page repeatedly (8 - 10 times), my page just keep the loading mode and no sign of stopping. First, i use MSSQL Server then i change to MySQL, nothing changed, i turn off the firewall, still not working.

**This my dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" cache-  period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hinet.storage" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" 
      p:viewClass=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"
      p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/database.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hinet.storage" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

**And this is RengencyDAOImpl:**

```
@Repository("regencyDAO")
@Transactional
public class RegencyDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl implements RegencyDAO{

    @Override
    public List<Regency> getRegencies() {
        String sql = "from Regency as re where re.isDelete != true";
        Query query = this.openSession().createQuery(sql, Regency.class);
        List<Regency> regencies = query.list();
        return regencies;
    }
}
```

> It has given me headache in the past few days! Does anyone know the
>   reason that cause this problem?

Comment: I think you exhaust your datasource (i.e opening without closing connection)

Comment: try to use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

Comment: What does `openSession()` do? I think it should be something like `getCurrentSession()`. If you open new session, you should close it.

Comment: @YCF_L what does it do?

Comment: I don't see any reason of using `@Transactional` for select, generally it used with persist and delete, so because you are using just select why you are using  `@Transactional` ?

Comment: @ThomasEdwin, thank you, i tried and it's worked

Comment: @NguyễnNgọcDuy I move my comments to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you exhaust your datasource (i.e opening without closing connection).
What does `openSession()` do? I think it should be something like `getCurrentSession()`.
If you open new session, you should close it.